# javascript - equal an array of numbers in the shortest way

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

i have an array which contain random numbers:

```
var EqualMe = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(),Math.random()];
```

Now lets say the numbers chosen are: 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1. I need to find a way to make an algorithm, that will equal each number to be 0.25 (since (0.4+0.3+0.2+0.1)/4 = 0.25) and I'm trying to do it in the fastest way possible by **withdrawing** a value from each number in the array to another.

So for this example the shortest way will be to withdraw from EqualMe[0] a value of 0.15 to EqualMe[3] and withdraw a value of 0.05 from EqualMe[1] to EqualMe[2] so each number in the array will be the same (0.25).

My question is how can I make a code, that can find the shortest way to withdraw values when the size of the array can be any given choice (not only 4 numbers) and the values in the array are completely random, so that the numbers will be perfectly equal with the lowest withdraws possible?

*please note:*
i need to code it for a money exchanging program for bitcoin wallets
each time i withdraw money from one wallet to another i lose fee
so i need to withdraw money from one wallet to another
with the lowest amount of withdraws possible so all the wallets will have the same value with giving total money

Comment: So you want to replace each element with average value?

Comment: We are not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Why would you need to "withdraw values" if you could simply replace value with an average?

Comment: @hindmost
not only replacing but finding the fastest way to withdraw

Comment: @epascarello 
this is not an homework, its a project i make 
that will equal few wallets of bitcoin by withdrawing from one to another
but i want it to to work with the lowest amount of withdraws

Comment: You have to clarify your problem. As it's currently written, it’s totally unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @hindmost im trying to make a program that withdraws money
from bitcoin wallets to make all the wallets equal in value
the only problem is that each time i withdraw money from one wallet to another i lose fee
so i need an algorithm in javascript which finds
where and how much money i need to withdraw from one wallet to another with the shortest amount of withdraws possible.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
I would find the average value of a set of numbers, calculate the difference for each of these compared to that number and SORT them by the greatest difference, then start divvying up those values into each to equal all to the average value. So you're matching up the biggest differences one by one (and sending any of the remainder to the NEXT item in line)

========
Example 1: 0.4, 0.3, 0.45, 0.25 (AVERAGE is 0.35)

The differences would be 0.1 (0.25), -0.1 (0.45), 0.05 (0.3), and -0.05 (0.4), making only TWO transactions needed to get 0.35 for all values.
**1st transaction** = FROM 0.45, move - 0.1 TO 0.25 = 0.35 for both
**2nd transaction** = FROM 0.4, move -.05 TO 0.3 = 0.35 for both

========
Example 2:
0.32, 0.47, 0.12, 0.56 (AVERAGE = 0.3675)

Differences (sorted in order) 0.2475 (0.12), -0.1925 (0.56), 0.1025 (0.47), 0.0475 (0.32)
**1st transaction** = FROM 0.56, move 0.1925 TO 0.12 (now equal to 0.3125)
**2nd transaction** = FROM 0.47, move 0.0550 to 0.12 (now equal to 0.3675)
**3rd transaction** = FROM 0.47, move 0.0475 to 0.32 (now equal to 0.3675

You MIGHT have more luck using a MEDIAN value versus an average in some cases, but I would probably set up BOTH, test which one uses the least transactions, then commit the one with the least transactions.

**ORIGINAL**
Instead of handling this programmatically, why not mathematically?

For instance, if you randomly generate the numbers, you could change their values to get the 0.25 you want.

If the total of your 4 random values equals 1.4 (0.4, 0.3, 0.45, 0.25), you could do 0.25/1.4 which is ~0.17 then multiply each of your values by 0.17 to reduce their value to then total 0.25.

(0.4 x 0.17) + (0.3 x 0.17) + (0.45 x 0.17) + (0.25 x 0.17) = ~0.25

Comment: yeah the only problem is that i need to make it
for money exchanging program
and i need to equal few wallets by withdrawing money to one another
,each time i withdraw money i lose fee, thats the reason why i'm trying to find the shortest way also

Comment: So are you ALWAYS trying to get 0.25 as the value for each? Or would this value be programmatically passed in? Or would it just simply be the number that requires the least amount of transactions so that all values are equal?

Comment: i have a total value if i add all the numbers together
lets say i have 4 wallets
and each one have a different value
but if you add all the numbers together to get one wallet
you get the value of 1 bitcoin
now since each wallet have a different value (like in the example i gave above)
i need to make an algorithm that will withdraw values from one wallet to another to make all the wallets have the same value with the ~same total
but the problem is that each time i withdraw money i lose fee
so i need to find the lowest withdraws way possible using an algorithm